# Retornar str dentro de array

Tags: javascript

Intento hacer que la condición dentro de la función pusheada retorne el string de cada indice si el código es correcto. Ej: `individualList[1](code) = 'str2'`

Agradecería si me ayudan a encontrar el error.

```
 function list(arr, cod) {
        let newArr = []
        for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            newArr.push(function(cod) {
                if (cod !== 123) return 'error'
                else return arr[i]
            })
        }
        return newArr
    }
    
    const array = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
    const code = 123

    const individualList = list(array, code)
```

Comment: No consigo entender qué pretendes hacer... declaras una función anónima y la almacenas en el array, pero nunca la invocas con lo cual tendrás un array de funciones, no de valores. Si eso es lo que quieres, el problema principal radica en que a esas funciones les indicas que tienen un parámetro (`cod`) pero en realidad nunca les estás pasando el parámetro! Tendrías que pasárselo luego a la hora de invocarlas por ejemplo `console.log(individualList[0](123));` imprimiría `"str1"`. Buscas algo [así](https://paiza.io/projects/f_7ovfffhZEKsijqwsCZNg)?

Comment: Sinceramente, no le veo el sentido a lo que pides (ni al paiza que te pasé, dicho sea de paso). Por qué? Porque basicamente estás haciendo un array de funciones ***idénticas***! Te recomiendo que si quieres que te ayuden con el *error* especifiques cual es dicho error, puesto que si no sé qué esperas conseguir, no sé qué puede estar mal.

Comment: Lo que intento hacer es que al poner individualList[1](code) retorne el string en ese indice. Con el código como está retorna undefined, entiendes?
En el paiza estas agregando un forEach para que eso suceda y debe retornar solo con la funcion 'list'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sinceramente, no veo necesario tener un montón de funciones diferentes que hacen básicamente lo mismo cuando podrías hacerlo desde una única función con el array de códigos dentro y pasándole `i` como parámetro, en vez de llamando a `lista[i]`!

---

De todos modos, aquí tienes tu código arreglado. He cambiado algunas cosas por comodidad y sobre todo, y esto ya es una recomendación, no es que esté mal, ***utiliza siempre punto y coma!***. Es cierto que JS permite ignorar los puntos y comas, pero es considerado buena práctica ponerlos. Además, también es considerado buena práctica utilizar siempre los corchetes aunque sea para una única línea (aunque eso me lo salté aquí :))

En los comentarios tienes las explicaciones de los cambios, cualquier duda, aquí estamos.

```js
/* 
 * Primero, no hay necesidad de pasarle el code, puesto que lo pasaremos
 * como parámetro a la función que obtenemos de aquí
 */
function list(arr) {
    let newArr = [];
    // En vez de un loop, utilizo un forEach y me olvido de la i
    arr.forEach((val) => {
        /*
         * Uso arrow functions por comodidad, pero es casi lo mismo
         * que utilizar funciones anónimas. En este caso simplemente me
         * permiten hacer lo mismo escribiendo menos código
         */
        newArr.push((cod) => {
            if (cod !== 123)
                return 'error';
            else
                return val;
        });
    });
    return newArr;
}

const array = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'];
const code = 123;

const l = list(array);
console.log(l[1](123));
console.log(l[2](1235315));
```

---

El problema que tenía tu código, es basicamente que no has declarado la variable `i` nunca antes de usarla, modifica el loop para que sea `for(let i=0;...` y ya está solucionado.

Por qué pasa eso? Pues porque estás intentando acceder a `arr[undefined]` y no existe, por eso te devuelve `undefined`.

Comment: Gracias Benito-B por las aclaraciones! de todas formas, en este ejercicio se pide no utilizar map o forEach. Por eso intentaba resolverlo con un for.
La consulta iba dirigida a porque retorna undefined y y no toma el valor de arr[i] en cada vuelta.

Comment: Puedes modificar este código añadiendo el for en vez del forEach y funcionará exactamente igual. El motivo por el que te está devolviendo `undefined` es que nunca has declarado la variable `i` que estás usando! Por eso te puse el ejemplo sin usar la `i`, pero si tienes que usar un for normal, simplemente modifica el for para que sea `for(let i=0...` y ya debería de funcionarte. Pero créeme, intenta acostumbrarte a seguir las *buenas prácticas* desde el principio, te ahorrará muchos dolores de cabeza!

Comment: Increible que haya sido eso. Gracias de nuevo Benito-B!